# How to get a value from a child node using a dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I use a dataset for reading a XML

```
ds.ReadXML(steam);
```

My XML look like this :

```
<models.Client>
    <id>1</id>
    <libelle>test</libelle>
    <nbSite>0</nbSite>
    <cabinet>false</cabinet>
    <clinique>false</clinique>
    <irm>0</irm>
    <scanner>0</scanner>
    <adresse>
        <id>1</id>
        <ligne1>1, rue toto</ligne1>
        <ligne2 />
        <codePostal />
        <ville />
        <coordonnee>
            <id>1</id>
            <telephone />
        </coordonnee>
    </adresse>
</models.Client>
```

How I can get the "ligne1" value ?
for "libelle", I get the value this way : 
`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["libelle"].ToString();` and it's ok, but "ligne1" is a child of models.Client.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be the second (index = 1) datatable, so:

```
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["ligne1"].ToString();
```

which will print: 1, rue toto